# Combine multiple bitmaps on Android using OpenCv

Tags: java, android, opencv, bitmap, mat

I want to join multiple images into one using openCV on android. The idea is to combine them vertically one followed by another.
I have tried this but I obtain black image.

```
   int totalHeigth = 0;
    List<Bitmap> bmps = getListCacheImages();
    Mat tmp = new Mat(allitemsheight,listView.getMeasuredWidth(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

    for (int i = 0; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
        Mat targetImage = new Mat();
        Utils.bitmapToMat(bmps.get(i), targetImage);
        //targetImage.row(0).copyTo(tmp.row(totalHeigth));
        targetImage.rowRange(0, bmps.get(i).getHeight()).colRange(0,width).copyTo(tmp.rowRange(totalHeigth, totalHeigth + bmps.get(i).getHeight()).colRange(0,width));
        totalHeigth += bmps.get(i).getHeight();
    }
    Imgcodecs.imwrite( mFolder.getPath() + "/" + filename + ".png",tmp);
```

The resulting image has appropriate measures but is empty. Only black is seen.

Can someone help me to combine the images? Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use that `colRange()` or `rowRange()` methods, Opencv has `hconcat()` to align the matrices(images Mat()) horizontally and `vconcat()` to align the matrices vertically, Keep in mind that dimension along which you are concatenating, must be equal. So in the given scenario, you may use the methods as :

```
Mat finalMat = new Mat();
Mat tempMat = new Mat();
Utils.bitmapToMat(bmps.get(0), finalMat);
for (int i = 1; i < bmps.size(); i++) {
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmps.get(i), tempMat);
    if (tempMat.cols() == finalMat.cols()){
        Core.vconcat(finalMat, tempMat, finalMat);
    }
    else{
    Log.d("debug", "The matrices don't have equal dimensions");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! I got it to work thanks to your code. But the method Core.vconcat is wrong. The first parameter must be a list of Mat. I have optimized the code this way:
    `List<Mat> mats = getListCacheImages();
        Mat tmp = new Mat(allitemsheight,width, CvType.CV_8U);
        for (int i = 1; i < mats.size(); i++) {
            if (mats.get(i).cols() == tmp.cols()){
                Core.vconcat(mats, tmp);
            }
            else{
                Log.d("debug", "The matrices don't have equal dimensions");
            }
        }`
It is better if you can change it